# Not able to access Office 365 Calendar Groups Feeds using REST API

Tags: rest, calendar, office365

[Office 365 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection5) suggests that we can access Calendar and Calendar Groups using REST APIs.

I am able to fetch My Calendars data which were created by me.
But when I try to hit Other Calendars which was shared with me, I get a null value.

```
{
   "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/$metadata#Users('mmmm.nnnn%40YYYY.COM')/CalendarGroups('AAMk........')/Calendars",
   "value":
   [
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nijin,
If you are using basic auth, you will be able to access the shared calendar events by using url  http://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Users('shareduseremail@domain.com')/Events

Remember though that this works because you are using basic auth which does not have a concept of consent.
It will not work if you use OAUTH, as you dont want an app to be to have access to calendars that others have shared with you.

Comment: Can you share the url that you are using. Specify what is the email of the user who is authenticated and what is the email of the user whose calendar you are trying to see. Does the shared user have events in his calendar?